# Modify home page

Tags: multistore, home

I must to make a modify only in home page.
How i can to understand if i am in home page?
I have tried with

```
$currentUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

but my url is:

http://www.miosito.com/it/?___from_store=en

The best solution are get urlkey but how to do? or to eliminate `?___from_store=en`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to check homepage

```
$routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();

if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home') {
    echo 'This is Magento Homepage.';
} else {
    echo 'This is not a Magento Homepage.';
}
```

From your comment i suggest you use above code  $identifier == 'home' change cms page 'home' identifier with your homepage identifier.

also alternative way to check is this home page

```
if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) {
    echo 'This is Magento Homepage.';
} else {
    echo 'This is not a Magento Homepage.';
}
```

Comment: I have insert this:
if ($this->getIsHomePage()) {
and work well if my home is
www.miosito.com/it/
but when i change language the url become
http://www.miosito.com/it/?___from_store=en

I need to remove
?___from_store=en

Comment: but it is only working in header.phtml because getIsHomePage() function of Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header block.

Comment: i have changed the file 
languages.phtml.
there is a string:
$_lang->getCurrentUrl()
modified
$_lang->getCurrentUrl(false)
work for me!